# Why OKHttp is designed as not to retry when SocketTimeoutException

Tags: android, http, okhttp

```
private boolean isRecoverable(IOException e, boolean requestSendStarted) {
    ....
    // If there was an interruption don't recover, but if there was a 
    //timeout connecting to a route
    // we should try the next route (if there is one).
     if (e instanceof InterruptedIOException) {
      return e instanceof SocketTimeoutException && !requestSendStarted;
    }
   ....
    return true;
}
```

Here is the code snippet in [RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/internal/http/RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java) in `OKHttp`.

My question is why `OkHttp` not retry when `SocketTimeoutException` and requestSendStarted == true?

Because I think if there are some other routers, we can retry another ip or router

Answer (score 3):

Consider the case where a request was successfully sent and the problem occurred when response data was transmitted to the client. Automatic retry in this case may make the server to repeat some action (increasing some count, writing a record somewhere) which may be undesirable. OKHttp lets the user to decide what to do in this case.

Comment: So you mean the user can catch this kind of Exceptions， and do something in custom interceptors?

Comment: @cafecat for instance in onFailure callback user can decide what to do - send another request or just display an error message or do some other thing.

Answer (score 2):

The goal was to retry if OkHttp couldn’t connect at all. If the server was reachable, but just responded slowly, then it’s just as likely to be an application-layer problem where retrying won’t help.

Comment: it makes sense to me, thx a lot. So if the user do want to retry, they can modify the OKHttp Source or catch this kind of Exceptions， and do something in custom interceptors?

Comment: Yeah, you can catch the exception in an interceptor and retry yourself.